# Pass data to picture export functionality on other domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a windows server 2008 with IIS 7. On this server I have a file storage containing images. I want to expose an export functionality. This export functionality will be called from SalesForce (other domain).

The problem is that the file names of the images are auto numbered random names. The actual information is stored in SalesForce. In order to give the user usable filenames (and folders) SalesForce will provide a JSON object containing the filenames and folders.

Something like this

```
{
    survey: "Sur-00000262"
    images : [   
    {"Sur-00000262_QUES-00001298_RESP-00002861.jpg":"folder/folder/filename.extension"},  
    {"Sur-00000262_QUES-00001299_RESP-00002861.jpg":"folder/filename.extension"},    
   ]   
}
```

My current solution is encoding the JSON as a base-64 string and passing this in the query string to the file export page.

The question is, is this the way to go or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it one request for one file, or do you need the entire JSON (which can contain 0-* files)?

Comment: @CodeCaster in theory it is for 1-* in practice it will be for somthing like 50-150 files. These files will be zipped and provided to the user as a zip file.

Comment: Can't you POST the JSON to the endpoint that downloads and zips the files?

Comment: @CodeCaster So a POST and return a download link? However te gathering of the files may take some time. So the file may not be ready when the link is returned.